# Can't change image source when useMap is set

Tags: javascript, html, dom, mouseevent, dom-manipulation

I'm trying to change the img.src on mouseover to load a different image. 

When I try to add this.useMap to the function or add usemap="#Map" to the HTML img tag the code doesn't work. I need to keep it in pure JavaScript, no jQuery.

What am I missing here?

```
<body>
<img id="stickyfooterimage" src="https://d3rm69wky8vagu.cloudfront.net/mediaspot/1.6089.gif" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,300,68" href="http://yahoo.com" target="_blank" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,69,300,150" href="http://google.com" target="_blank" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,151,300,250" href="http://aol.com" target="_blank" />
</map>
</body>
<script>
var stickyFooterMouseOver = "https://d3rm69wky8vagu.cloudfront.net/mediaspot/1.6088.gif"

var stickyImage = document.getElementById('stickyfooterimage');

var stickyFooterMouseDefault = stickyImage.src;

stickyImage.onmouseover = function () {
    this.src = stickyFooterMouseOver;
    //this.useMap = "#Map";
};

stickyImage.onmouseout = function () {
    this.src = stickyFooterMouseDefault;
};
<script>
```

Code here:http://jsfiddle.net/connectedcat/rt9sm/

OK, I rigged it to work the way I want:

```
<body>

    <img id="stickyfooterimage" src="https://d3rm69wky8vagu.cloudfront.net/mediaspot/1.6089.gif" usemap="#Map"/>
    <map name="Map" id="Map">
      <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,300,69" href="http://yahoo.com" target="_blank" onmouseover="useBig()" onmouseout="useSmall()"/>
      <area shape="rect" coords="0,69,300,150" href="http://google.com" target="_blank" onmouseover="useBig()" onmouseout="useSmall()"/>
      <area shape="rect" coords="0,150,300,250" href="http://aol.com" target="_blank" onmouseover="useBig()" onmouseout="useSmall()"/>

    </map>



</body>
<script>


    var stickyFooterMouseOver = "https://d3rm69wky8vagu.cloudfront.net/mediaspot/1.6088.gif"


    var stickyImage = document.getElementById('stickyfooterimage');

    var stickyFooterMouseDefault = stickyImage.src;

    function useBig() {
        stickyImage.src = stickyFooterMouseOver;
    }
    function useSmall() {
        stickyImage.src = stickyFooterMouseDefault;
    }

</script>
```

I would still like to know what's going on here. It seems that assigning the usemap attribute to img sets a whole new element on top of the img and the mouse events don't fire on mouseover and mouseout? I'm just guessing, so if anybody has a good explanation I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

`useMap` is not a property, it's an attribute. You need to use a DOM method to add it to the element.

```
this.setAttribute("usemap", "Map");
```

Comment: Does not work. It sets the usemap="Map". I need usemap="#Map", according to the specs:http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_usemap.asp <br/>If i set it up to this.setAttribute('usemap', '#Map') - the image src doesn't change.

Comment: I think it would be easier to have both in-place on the screen and hide one and show the other rather than swapping usemap and src.